# Variable who's reference is always to len(dict)

Tags: python, dictionary, increment, variable-length

```
cardPayments={}
rowNumber, NumOfCardPayments = 0, len(cardPayments)

for x in range(5):
    cardPayments.update({x:x})
    print(cardPayments)
    print('cardPayments: '+str(NumOfCardPayments)+'\n')
```

Output:

```
{0: 0}
cardPayments: 0

{0: 0, 1: 1}
cardPayments: 0

{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
cardPayments: 0

{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
cardPayments: 0

{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
cardPayments: 0
```

I was hoping that by referencing `NumOfCardPayments` to `len(cardPayments)` that as `cardPayments` dict increased in size so would the int value of `NumOfCardPayments` during the for loop, this seems to not be the case.

How can I create `NumOfCardPayments` as a variable which is maintained as a reference of `len(cardPayments)`?

(Please note, I would not like to simply do `NumOfCardPayments+=1` within the for loop)

Comment: Why can't you just use `len(cardPayments)` each time?

Comment: Thanks for the input Tyler, the question wasn't so much based around the easiest way to solve the problem presented but instead 'how to solve the problem in this specific way'.  I agree it may, with reference to the example, not be the most simplified or efficient but it was the understanding of how to do it that I was interested in.

Comment: No worries, that's why I was asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing that comes to mind is a property, which automatically evaluates a function when read:

```
>>> class LenDict(dict):
...   @property
...   def len(self):
...     return len(self)
...
>>> d=LenDict()
>>> d.len
0
>>> d[1]=2
>>> d.len
1
>>>
```

But IMHO this is no clearer than using `len(d)` directly, and certainly not as efficient. It's also possible to place the hook the other way around by wrapping setitem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible. In Python, variables contain pointers to objects. Integer objects are immutable. Therefore, the only way to change the value of numOfCardPayments is to bind it to a new object...

Comment: @Robert: binding a variable to a new object is done by assignment. You would need to do `NumOfCardPayments = len(cardPayments)` each time before you use `NumOfCardPayments`. It seems better to simply use `len(cardPayments)` each time.

Comment: Another option is to replace `numOfCardPayments` with a function: `def numOfCardPayments(): return len(cardPayments)` and then use `numOfCardPayments()`

Comment: One could even hide the function using a property. Still no more readable than just using len() in the first place.

Comment: Could you give an example of this please Yann?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a simple lambda object to return the length of a specific object

```
def len_follower(target_object):
    return lambda : len(target_object)
```

Then set the parameter `target_object` as  `cardPayments`

```
>>>cardPayments = {}
>>>NumOfCardPayments = len_follower(cardPayments)
>>>NumOfCardPayments()
0
>>>cardPayments[1] = 0
>>>NumOfCardPayments()
1
```